# getchar() != EOF

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am running the following program from the [C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  int c;
  while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(); 
}
```

Or

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int c = getchar();
   while(c != EOF){
      putchar(c);
      c = getchar();
   }
}
```

When I run this program, I get an unexplained behavior.  If I input characters from the command line in the following sequence: `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\n', '^D'}` then I get the following response printed to screen: `hello`, after `\n` is input, and the program quits once `^D` in entered.

However, when I change the sequence as follows: `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '^D'}` then I get the following response printed to screen: `hello`, but the program does not quit.  Shouldn't it quit once I enter `^D`?  I have to enter `^D` a second time for the program to quit.  OR the program only quits after I have entered `^D` following `\n`.  I don't understand why the program doesn't quit no matter when I enter `^D`.  Any thoughts?

I am running on a UNIX system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you type ^D ('end-of-transmission') the input buffer is flushed and everything you typed until now is sent to your program (without actually sending ^D character). It is similar to typing newline character, however, in this case the newline character itself is sent too. A program considers its input as closed when it reads zero characters. This happens when you type newline followed by ^D or two consecutive ^D.

Comment: note that this is a property of the operating system input stream, not of the C program.

Comment: Thank you, Marian and Matt McNabb.  I thought that the input buffer is only flushed by typing newline character.  I was not aware of a similar behavior with ^D as well.