# why it doesn't print the result?(I've already tapped ctrl+z(windows10) after the input)

Tags: c

Why doesn't it print the result? I've already tapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after the input.

**code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*histogram of frequences of chars*/
main()
{
    int charIn, numa, numb;
    numa = numb = 0 ;
    while ((charIn == getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (charIn =='a')
            ++numa;
        if (charIn =='b')
            ++numb; 
    }
    printf("A:%d\n",numa);
    printf("B:%d\n",numb);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop is running infinitely. Change

```
while ((charIn == getchar()) != EOF)
```

to

```
while ((charIn = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Also note that you are using `charIn` before initialization in  `(charIn == getchar())` and it will invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

- It is not printing output because your while loop is not ending.Try below code.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  /*histogram of frequences of chars*/
  int main()
  {
     int  numa, numb, i;
     numa = numb = i = 0 ;
     int charIn;
     while(1)
     {
        while ((charIn = getchar()) != EOF && charIn != '\n')
        {
           if (charIn =='a')
              ++numa;
           if (charIn =='b')
              ++numb;
        }
        printf("A:%d\n",numa);
        printf("B:%d\n",numb);
        numa = numb = 0;
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: However，if so, how can I input newlines?

Comment: @luc: see updated code as u asked.

Answer (score 0):

First off, change `(ch==getchar()) != EOF` to `(ch=getchar()) != EOF`. The first one is comparing `ch`, which is never initialized, to the value returned by `getchar()`. And the second one is giving the value returned by `getchar()` to `ch`, which is what you actually mean.

Next, note that you can **never** end an unnested loop using `(ch=getchar()) != EOF`. see [getchar() != EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183865/5399734). Instead, use `(ch=getchar()) != '\n'`, and it will work.

BTW: Your program will be better if you bother to write `int main()` and `return 0;`.

Comment: Of course you can. And this isn't the OP's problem, it is a simple typo, == instead of =.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I notice that now. At least on my machine, I've never ended a loop successfully using `(ch=getchar()) != EOF`. There will always be an extra '\n'.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, I know. You are right.

Comment: @Lundin Is there any method to end an unnested loop using `(ch=getchar()) != EOF` then?

Answer (score 0):

```
(charIn == getchar())
```

Is a condition. `==` is a comparison operator. You want to set your char though, so use

```
while ((charIn = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Additionally, you should initialize your `charIn` with the rest of your numbers, as failing to do so invoked Undefined behavior.

Now, if you want to stop on newlines and not the EOF char (which is actually not even a char really) then you need to check against newlines, or `'\n'`, so like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*histogram of frequencies of chars*/
main()
{
    int charIn, numa, numb;
    numa = numb = charIn = 0;

    while ((charIn = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (charIn =='a')
            ++numa;
        if (charIn =='b')
            ++numb; 
    }

    printf("A:%d\n",numa);
    printf("B:%d\n",numb);
}
```