# Basic character counting in C

Tags: c, character, counting

Having trouble getting an actual count, but I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

I type in a word, hit enter, then nothing happens and it keeps running.

```
int main(void)
{    
  double nc;

  for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
      ;
  printf ("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth do you use a floating-point number for counting?

Comment: I'm just following this book, the c programming language

Comment: I am not suggesting that you should toss that book away ASAP, but you probably should, anyway. Floating-point numbers are imprecise and should never be used for counting. Use integer numbers. As for your question, you must press ^D to close input.

Comment: You have to end the input with either ENTER followed by ctrl-D, or two ctrl-d's back to back. this is similar to an earlier question. Read the answers there for some background.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183865/getchar-eof

Comment: Someone suggested the book to me as I have never coded before, and I wanted to start with some basic stuff

Comment: Is there a book anyone suggests for someone who has barely any knowledge about all this

Comment: If you want code to stop at the end of a _line_, detect `'\n'`.  `int ch; for (nc = 0; ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'); ++nc)
      ;`

Comment: @Wayne If you mean the book by Kernighan & Ritchie, it's a good book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading from an interactive console input, `getchar()` will not return `EOF` just because the user stops typing or presses return, it will if necessary wait for the user to enter something new on the keyboard. So, the for-loop is not terminated.

You have to use a special key combination (dependent on the operating system used) to signal end-of-file or check for some other input to terminate the loop (like end-of-line, for example)

Comment: This is not true. If you press ^D (or a similar character in a Mac terminal), an `EOF` marker is generated, and `getchar()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: @DYZ answer clarified

Comment: It would be better if you mention what those special key combinations to trigger `EOF` are, at least for linux and windows, in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, EOF will not be true until ^D is entered. Terminate on that, but also check for the newline character. Check this older Question for some good background on this here:
[getchar() != EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27183865/6693299)

Here is the program written using ints and checking for newline or EOF

```
// Customize AT_END Macro to return true based on some condition
#define AT_END(ch) (((ch)=='\n') || ((ch)==EOF)) 

int main(void)
{    
  int  inpChar = getchar();
  int  nc      = 0;

  while (!AT_END(inpChar)) {
      nc++;
      inpChar = getchar();
  };

  printf("Number of chars=%d\n", nc);
}
```