# getchar(), putchar(char), EOF

Tags: eof, getchar, putchar

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int c = getchar();
   while(c != EOF){
      putchar(c);
      c = getchar();
   }
}
```

In above code why does not the program terminates by itself after c becomes EOF?
Reference of the code > Book: K&R's The C Programming Language 2nd Edition,
Page: 18

Comment: It terminates for me  when I type <ctrl-D> as an input in an Ubuntu Linux terminal. Just hitting return won't cause getchar() to return EOF (-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getchar() != EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183865/getchar-eof)

Answer (score 0):

getchar() will return EOF only if the end of file is reached. The ‘file’ here is the standard input itself.
This can be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
   int main()
  {
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
     /*getchar() returns the the next available value which is in the input
     buffer*/    
     putchar(c);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please make me sure that you are not claiming the code you modified above will cause to reach EOF terminating program by itself